# displaying x-axis labels properly in matplotlib plots

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot electricity usage against time. I'm using this script:

```
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

timelist = []
valuelist = []

# Logic that populates timelist and valuelist

timeaxis = np.array(timelist)
valueaxis = np.array(valuelist)

plt.plot(timeaxis, valueaxis, 'r-')
plt.savefig('elec_use.png', bbox_inches='tight')
plt.show()
```

The x-axis labels in the plot I get running the program above is all crammed into the length of the graph. [image: x-axis labels crammed]

I tried rotating the labels by adding `xticks`  like so:

```
plt.xticks(timeaxis, rotation=90)
```

This causes the labels to get trimmed. [image: x-axis labels cut off]

How can I fix the problem? I have tried adding `plt.gcf().subplots_adjust(bottom=0.25)` but this does not fix the labels, it merely increases the real estate to the bottom of the graph. I want the x-axis labels to say `Jun 02 2016` or simply `Jun 02`. I don't mind the graph being wide. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [gcf().autofmt_xdate](http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.autofmt_xdate) to format the x-axis nicely. And for the date string format, you could use `matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter`. It will be something like below:

[image]

---

So you code will be something like this:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)

timelist = []
valuelist = []

# Logic that populates timelist and valuelist

timeaxis = np.array(timelist)
valueaxis = np.array(valuelist)
ax.plot(timeaxis, valueaxis, 'r-')

# rotate and align the tick labels so they look better
fig.autofmt_xdate()

# use a more precise date string for the x axis locations in the
# toolbar
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
ax.fmt_xdata = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d')
plt.savefig('elec_use.png', bbox_inches='tight')
plt.show()
```